# Speed up SQL Server 2008 query using index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have a query like below

```
    Select top(10) *
    from myTable
    where CreateTime between '2014-2-3' and '2014-2-5' 
    and (Result is null or Result != 1)
```

But when i build an index like below

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Index] ON [dbo].[mytable] 
    (
[CreateTime] ASC,
    Result ASC
    )
    INCLUDE ( [ID])
```

([ID] is primary Key of mytable)

Sql server does not use that index

how can i speed up above query?

Comment: there is ResultR or Result column?

Comment: For what it's worth `INCLUDE (ID)` is redundant if ID is your clustering/primary key, the clustering key is always included in the index, it is required to perform any lookups. I'd guess the reason your index isn't being used is you are using `SELECT *` and SQL Server has determined that the cost of the key lookup required to get all the columns is more than a clustered index scan, so is doing the cheaper of the two options. If you want to force the use of an index you can use the `WITH (INDEX (Index_Name))` query hint, but use with care, usually the optimiser knows best.

Comment: yes, ResultR is Result

Comment: Replicating the query - I easily get a seek based on the structure we can see. So the actual answer is indeterminable by the information given. So we need to know how the table schema is and how much data do you have in the table. Are statistics up to date and are indexes fragmented? Have you dropped execution plans to avoid reusing an old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to simply build the index like

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Index] ON [dbo].[mytable] 
(
   [CreateTime]
)
```

Since you are filtering on `CreateTime`, just build a covering index on that column. I don't think that adding `Result` to the index will help the query.

Also you don't have to include the primary key column in the index, SQL Server does that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use if you want to force sql server to use specific index.

```
Select top(10) *
from myTable WITH (INDEX(IX_Index))
where CreateTime between '2014-2-3' and '2014-2-5' 
and (Result is null or Result != 1)
```

Comment: Using a table hint isn't a good practice. You should try to create the right covering index for the query, instead of blindly forcing SQL Server to use that index. A hint like that could even give you worse performances.

Comment: @mordack550 I disagree completely with this *"Using a table hint isn't a good practice."*. Even assuming you only mean the use index table hint, not all table hints, I'd say that forcing an index via a table hint is probably best approached with caution, but there are occasions when I have had to use it, and it certainly isn't bad practice.

Comment: @GarethD I understand that using table hints often is very useful, I used them sometimes on DBs where the query optimizer could not choose the right method to read a table, but I find it's always better trying to understand why SQL choose that specific query plan and address the issue directly. Suppose to have other queries that use that table, will you add a table hint on every single one of them?

Comment: I agree that understanding why a query plan is used is better, but that does not make using a table hint *bad practice*, that is a sweeping generalization and I don't agree with it. It is kind of like watching someone eat soup with a fork and then say that using a fork is bad practice. By that logic anything can be bad practice if done incorrectly, or by someone that doesn't understand why they are doing it.

Comment: @mordack550 I have met cases that the query optimizer doesn't choose the best index there. In such case, I would like to force using one index which will return better result. The query optimizer is good in many cases, but not the smartest in some edge cases. Saying it's not a good practice is not reasonable to me.

Comment: @zhongxiao37 it seems I have used the wrong term. What I meant was that I consider forcing the use of a specific index only in cases where the query optimizer could not choose the right plan, even if statistics are updated and indexes and the query itself are well designed. For me that's always the last resort.